# ReactJS + Redux: How to structure action creators down to each component?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

I have one parent component called `App.js`:

```
...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props}
    </div>
  )
}

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return (
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, 
  )
}

export default connect(
  ...,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

And the props would be passed down to each component. I would like to have each component to have its action creators file, but then how can I tie all the action creators into one so that the action creators can be passed down from the `App.js` level? Any other suggestions would be appreciated too to have action creators down to each component.

Here is the structure so far:

```
ComponentOne
..actions.js //action creators
..ComponentOne.js
ComponentTwo
..actions.js //action creators
..ComponentTwo.js
App.js
actions.js//should I compile all the action creators here?
```

And each `actions.js` would be made like so:

```
let actions = {
  logSayings() {
    ...
  }
}

export default actions
```

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept answer.

**REDUX SET UP**

store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

let finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk, logger())
)(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState = {articles: []}) {
  return finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState)
}
```

actions.js

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

let actions = {
  updateBar(status) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_BAR',
      indicator: status
    }
  }
}

export default actions
```

homeReducer.js

```
const homeReducer = function(articles = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_BAR':
      return {
        indicator: action.indicator,
      }

    default:
      return articles
  }
}

export default homeReducer
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import configureStore from '../../redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

import App from './components/App'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'

let initialState = {

}

let store = configureStore(initialState)

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={App}
          path='/'
        >
          <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector('.wrapper')
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to have action creators on all your child components? why you cant centralize your actions on App's mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: @Robsonsjre I've done that but it got to a point where it got too clustered. Too many action creators, and I would have to always scroll through the irrelevant ones and find the one that I need. Having action creators for a particular component helps me to look up and take action much more quicker on action creators.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I usually structure my react/redux app.

I keep actions outside of the components & containers. I usually try and name my action files specific to areas of the app that I'm building. e.g. UsersActions, ProductActions, OrdersActions, CheeseActions works too...

```
App
  actions
    CheeseActions.js
    ...
  components
    CheeseBox.js
  containers
    CheeseApp.js
  ...
```

Example Container - Let the container handle the actions. (Kinda like a controller.)

```
// import the actions that this container needs to do it's job.
import { makeCheese, sellCheese } from '../actions/CheeseActions'
import CheeseBox from '../components/CheeseBox'

class CheeseApp extends Component {

  // Let the container handle the actions
  onPurchasePressed(kind) {
    dispatch(sellCheese(kind))
  }

  // More actions...

  render() {
    return(
      <CheeseBox onPurchase={this.onPurchasePressed.bind(this)} />
    )
  }

}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CheeseApp)
```

Example Component - We're going to let the container handle the function,
using this.props.onPurchase('Cheddar').

```
// Cheesebox is dumb, keep him that way.
export default class CheeseBox extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    onPurchase: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const { onPurchase } = this.props
    return(
      <p>Hi, I love cheese.</p>
      <a onClick={() => onPurchase('Cheddar')} />Buy Now!</a>
    )
  }

}
```

Hopefully this is helpful. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is going modular nature wise. This way the code will be cleaner and readable.

```
App
  action/
    component1Actions.js
    ...
    componentnActions.js
    actionTypes.js
  components/
    Component1.js
    ...
    Componentn.js
  container/
    Component1.js
    ...
    Componentn.js
  reducers/
    component1Reducer.js
    ...
    componentnReducer.js
```

The structure shown above is what most of the developers I have encountered have used (I prefer this approach). This makes sense because we separate each file based on the nature of that file. This approach is suitable for small to medium projects where there are not that many separate files.

In large apps, it often becomes difficult to maintain the code.

Another school of thought is going [domain-wise](https://marmelab.com/blog/2015/12/17/react-directory-structure.html)

```
app/
  ...
  App.js
  reducers.js
  routes.js
  product/
    Product.js
    ProductContainer.js
    productReducer.js
    ...
  user/
    User.js
    UserContainer.js
    UserActions.js
    userReducer.js
    ...
```

The benefit of this is that we separate files based on its domain. For e.g. an app needs a User component. It would be easier if we kept all the files related to that domain under one directory. This would make the app structure cleaner in large applications.

Both have benefits. At the end of the day, the structure doesn't matter. It is more of a personal choice.

Comment: Really appreciate the insight! Trying to separate the files based on its domain, and with the current set up, I am having trouble doing so. I've updated the original post with my current redux set up. The reducers are separated, but actions are not. Do you mind showing how to revise the set up to make it work based on its domain? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/koshuang/react-redux-starter-kit . This might offer a better explanation of this structure.

Answer (score 1):

I can think about two approaches:

- Combining your actionObjects all in one at App.js's mapDisatchToProps
- Each of your components can become a 'container' component

Example 1:

```
App.js

import actionObj1 from '../actionComponent1'

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  Object.assign({}, actionObj1, actionObj2, actionObj3)
)(App)
```

UPDATE (each child component become container, just connect like on App.js):

```
Component1.js

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actionObj1)
)(Component1)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on making each component become a 'container' component? And could I combine all into one action creators sheet rather than importing each individual action creators sheet? Is there a better approach to this in the same logic?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something that you may want to look at is changing your redux folder structure to be more modular. You wont have bloated action files and it should be easier to maintain than have large action/type/reducer files that encompass all of your redux actions.

I like to separate my redux actions, types, and reducers into modules in the following way:

In my `src` folder, I will have a `modules` folder. In this `modules` folder, I will have sub-folders for different types of data in my application state. For example, a folder for `auth`, a folder for `posts`, and a folder for `comments`. I will also have a `index.js`.

In each folder, I will have an `actions.js` file, a `types.js` file, and a `reducer.js` file.

In each `action.js` file, I will only place in actions that pertain to that type of data.

For example, in the `actions.js` file of my `posts` folder, I will have the action creators `listPosts`, `getPost`, etc. The structure of my action creator is slightly different from what you might see because of the custom middleware that I use, but a great example of a middleware you can use as inspiration or copy is here: [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/redux/middleware/clientMiddleware.js). [They use a similar style of putting redux items in modules](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/tree/master/src/redux/modules), although they prefer to put them all action creators, types, and reducers in combined files while I like to keep mine separate.

```
import types from './types';

export const getPost = id => ({
  type: types.LOAD_POST_DETAIL,
  responseTypes: [types.LOAD_POST_DETAIL_SUCCESS, types.LOAD_POST_DETAIL_FAILURE],
  promise: client => client.get(`/posts/${id}`),
});

export const listPosts = () => ({
  type: types.LIST_POSTS,
  responseTypes: [types.LIST_POSTS_SUCCESS, types.LIST_POSTS_FAILURE],
  promise: client => client.get('/posts'),
});
```

In each `types.js` file, I will only place in types that pertain to that type of data. 
For example, my `types.js` file might look like this:

```
export default {
  LOAD_POST_DETAIL: 'LOAD_POST_DETAIL',
  LOAD_POST_DETAIL_SUCCESS: 'LOAD_POST_DETAIL_SUCCESS',
  LOAD_POST_DETAIL_FAILURE: 'LOAD_POST_DETAIL_FAILURE',

  LIST_POSTS: 'LIST_POSTS',
  LIST_POSTS_SUCCESS: 'LIST_POSTS_SUCCESS',
  LIST_POSTS_FAILURE: 'LIST_POSTS_FAILURE',

  UPDATE_POST: 'UPDATE_POST',
  UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS: 'UPDATE_POST_SUCCESS',
  UPDATE_POST_FAILURE: 'UPDATE_POST_FAILURE',
};
```

My reducer will only have reducer functions specific to that type of data.

An example for the `reducer.js` file in my `posts` folder:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import type { Reducer } from 'redux';
import { get, assign } from 'lodash';
import types from './types';

const all = (
  state = { isFetching: false, data: [] },
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LIST_POSTS:
      return assign({}, state, { isFetching: true });
    case types.LIST_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return assign({}, state, get(action, 'result.data'), { isFetching: false });
    default: return state;
  }
};

export const reducer = combineReducers({ all });
```

In the `index.js` of the `modules` folder, you can export all of your reducers (to be combined when you create your redux store) like so:

```
export { reducer as auth } from './auth/reducer';
export { reducer as posts } from './posts/reducer';
export { reducer as comments } from './comments/reducer';
```

When you `import` an action, you would simply do something like

```
import { listPosts } from 'modules/posts/actions';
```

Setting up your redux folder structure to have a more modular design can save you a lot of headache since there is a clear pattern to where functions will be placed and where to import your functions from.

Comment: Appreciate your repsonse Yo. Where would all the action creators be placed?

Comment: @JoKo, I updated my answer so that it gives an example of some action creators in my actions.js file. Note that my action creators are structured slightly different from what you might normally see, but that is because I use a custom middleware that is based off of the one linked, but it is fairly specific to my implementations so isn't significantly different functionally than the one I linked. I also put some notes on a promise/client middleware and posted a link to an example middleware you can get inspiration from, along with a linked example of the modular separation of store items.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share a blog post I tought might be relevant here https://marmelab.com/blog/2015/12/17/react-directory-structure.html

But in general I agree with Breet's answer, and disagree with the blog's opinion (: